# Is it okay to ask for reimbursement for an interview even if I got an offer?

Tags: hiring-process, ethics, reimbursement

I had a job interview last week with a very big company and I got an offer from them. I have mixed opinions on asking for reimbursement at this point, because I got the offer I wanted and I don't want to look like I am not satisfied with this and asking for more.

**If I ask for reimbursement at this point, would that leave a bad impression on them?**

---

I am talking about the travel and accommodation expenses for the interview ($150). Please note that they offered me a hotel room because I was coming from a long way. They sent me the reimbursement form when we set the interview date. So it was before I went there.

Comment: Reimbursement of travel expenses for the interview? Are they significant - tens of dollars, hundreds? Did they mention reimbursement at all in the process - have they just forgotten to do the paperwork, or might they be surprised if you ask?

Comment: Reimbursement for what? Interview travel expenses? Relocation? Something else?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question.  You traveled and got a hotel room to do an interview.  They sent you a reimbursement form, so clearly they expected to pay for the interview, which they will deduct as a business expense.  Why wouldn't you turn in the reimbursement form?

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/40580/1898

Comment: The question title seems like it doesn't really match the actual question. You're not asking for reimbursement, you're simply submitting a claim for reimbursement that's already been offered.

Comment: Just for future reference (and because the OP has 'Germany' stated as their location in the profile): A location tag might be relevant for this question, because e.g. in Germany companies are required by law to pay your (reasonable) travel expenses for an interview, independent of the result, unless they exclude it beforehand. So it would be absolutely fine to send the company your receipts even if they don't hand you a special form for this during the interview process.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

> Is it okay to ask for reimbursement even if I got an offer?

Yes, that is why they gave you the form before the interview. It's a normal part of their procedures.

Whether you got the job or not makes no difference.

Comment: Especially in a big company, the important people for your career might never know about this, so it really doesn't matter

Comment: The important people for your career at the company will expect you to be reimbursed for the expenses you incurred to come work for them.

Answer (score 19):

Here's the question in reverse: This company promised to reimburse you for your expenses.  If you ask them to back up their promise and they hold it against you, then, simply put, they think it is OK to make empty promises to you, and they think it is OK to get upset when you call those empty promises.

Is that sort of company really the sort of company you want to work for?  When considering this, keep in mind that a salary is simply just a form of promise: "I promise that if you do this work for me then I will give you some money at a later date".  How would you feel if this empty promise that the company does not want to fulfill was your salary?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, of course it's okay. Why would it not be?

If anything, ignoring what you were told to do would give a bad impression.

You were given simple instructions. Follow them.

Answer (score 6):

They gave you a form, fill it out and send it back as they've asked you to.

What's the problem chief?